# Import text fields from for into Javascript function

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to grab the value from each text field in the form, multiply it by a set value in a global variable, and put the result in a table. I first import the global array "workouts". It looks like this:

```
var workouts = [
["Workout1", 0.68, 0.7, 0.72, 0.75, 0.8],
["Workout2", 0.68, 0.7, 0.72, 0.75, 0.8],
["Workout3", 0.68, 0.7, 0.72, 0.75, 0.8]
]
```

Next, I create a form using a javascript for loop like so:

```
<script>
document.write('<form id = "maxes">')
for(var i = 0; i < workouts.length; i++){
    document.write(workouts[i][0] + ': <input type="text" value="100"/> <br>');
    forms.push("in" + String(i))
}
document.write('<button type="submit">Go</button>')
document.write('</form>')
</script>
```

Then, on submit, I call another javascript function that should grab the data and use it to create a table.

```
<script>
function processForm(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();

    document.write('<table style = "border: 1px solid black;">')
    for(var i = 0; i < workouts.length; i++){
        document.write('<tr style = "border: 1px solid black;"><td>' + workouts[i][0] + '</td>');
        document.write('<td style = "border: 1px solid black;">' + (workouts[i][1] * document.getElementById("maxes")[i]) + '</td> </tr>')
    }
    document.write('</table>')
    // You must return false to prevent the default form behavior
    return false;
}

var form = document.getElementById('maxes');
if (form.attachEvent) {
    form.attachEvent("submit", processForm);
} else {
    form.addEventListener("submit", processForm);
}
</script>
```

However, through all of the methods I have tried, I can only seem to get either null or undefined back for the form. This then throws the error that there is no "value" aspect of null/undefined.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can only do a document.write in Javascript while the page is still loading. If you use it after the completion of the rendering (like in your case in the `processForm` function), the the whole previous content of the page will be made blank, and replaced with the content that you are writing.

In your case, when you call processForm, you second line empties the document content and replaces it with the new value:

```
document.write('<table style = "border: 1px solid black;">')
```

Then, when you get to the part where it gets the form with `getElementById`, all that is found on the document is the opening tag of the table, so it's all null.

I suggest that you completely change your approach and use jQuery, but if you really need to use the document.write approach, you should call the function only once at the end the processForm function:

```
function processForm(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();

    var newContent = "";

    newContent += '<table style = "border: 1px solid black;">';
    for (var i = 0; i < workouts.length; i++) {
        newContent += '<tr style = "border: 1px solid black;"><td>' + workouts[i][0] + '</td>';
        newContent += '<td style = "border: 1px solid black;">' + (workouts[i][1] * parseInt(document.getElementById("maxes")[i].value)) + '</td> </tr>';
    }
    newContent += '</table>';

    document.write(newContent);
    return false;
}
```

I have also made a couple of fixes to the code so that the number from the field is read correctly (using `parseInt` and `.value`).

Answer (score 0):

Do something like document.getElementsByTagName('input'). Loop through the array of elements. If the element.getAttribute('type') is 'text' grab the element.getAttribute('value').

Answer (score 0):

Further to the comments made by Stefano regarding the use of `document.write` and `parseInt` and `.value`, I suggest there are a couple of extra points that may be made.

Namely:

- you could be using a css rule to style your output table.
- you could be making use of the `this` keyword in your processForm
  function (the `processForm` function is a 'part' of the form object when attached using `addEventListener`, as such, the `this` keyword in that function refers to the form itself)
- you could use a pre-existing target for your output. This would give you the advantage of showing you the result each and every time you click the `Go` button, rather than every second time, as is now my observation.

Here's my take on it, aimed at being a (working) improvement and at avoiding going into too many new concepts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

var workouts = 
[
    ["Workout1", 0.68, 0.7, 0.72, 0.75, 0.8],
    ["Workout2", 0.68, 0.7, 0.72, 0.75, 0.8],
    ["Workout3", 0.68, 0.7, 0.72, 0.75, 0.8]
];

function makeForm()
{
    var i, content='', form = byId('maxes');

    for (i=0; i<workouts.length; i++)
        content += workouts[i][0] + ": <input type='text' value='100'/><br>"
    content += "<button type='submit'>Go</button>";
    form.innerHTML = content;
    form.addEventListener('submit', processForm, false);
}

function processForm(evt)
{
    var cellValue, content = '', i, theForm = this;

    if (evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();

    content = '<table>';
    for(i = 0; i < workouts.length; i++)
    {
        cellValue = workouts[i][1] * parseInt(theForm.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value);
        content += '<tr><td>' + workouts[i][0] + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + cellValue + '</td></tr>';
    }
    content += '</table>';
    byId('output').innerHTML = content;

    // You must return false to prevent the default form behavior
    return false;
}

window.addEventListener('load', makeForm, false);
</script>
<style>
table, tr, td
{
    border: solid 1px black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id='maxes'></form>
    <div id='output'></div>
</body>
</html>
```